# Anaconda-Navigator app not launching in macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, path, anaconda, macos-catalina

I note that when I install Anaconda in a custom folder (within the Documents folder) running macOS Catalina the Anaconda-Navigator app does not launch. Running from Terminal the following error is shown:

```
open /Applications/Anaconda-Navigator.app
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Applications/Anaconda-Navigator.app.
```

Reviewing the Console app the following error is also shown:

```
Sandbox: bash(12878) System Policy: deny(1) file-read-data /Users/[user]/Documents/Python/anaconda2/bin/activate
```

Now I can successfully launch the application by running `anaconda-navigator` in Terminal. It was after some searching I realised that the new Catalina permissions will restrict access to the Documents folder where I installed anaconda.

This I tested by looking at the first line of the code in `/Applications/Anaconda-Navigator.app/Contents/MacOS/run.sh`. This called the shell `#!/bin/sh`. I then added the `sh` binary to the Full Disk Access permission and I was able to launch the application without error.

Now I am a bit weary of leaving `sh` with Full Disk Access so I've removed it for now. I am hoping that there will be an update to the installer for Catalina which will fix this for custom installation paths for Anaconda in the future.

> As an update to this issue, I removed and reinstalled the package to a folder outside the documents folder `~/Python/anaconda2` and then re-ran the conda init to fix the shell command:
>
> ```
> source ~/Python/anaconda2/bin/activate
> conda init zsh
> ```
>
> After this everything worked as expected.